# Indexing across multiple intervals

Tags: python

I am trying to extract the n-th element from a set of multiple intervals. I am currently dealing with genome sequences. Assume we have a gene with a gap in the middle. The position of this gene within the whole DNA is:

```
gene = [100,110], [130,140]
# representing the lists [100,101,...,109] and [130, 131,...,139]
# the gene spans over these entries of the DNA, so it looks like -gene-gap-gene-
```

Now, for a position within the gene (e.g. 10th position), I want to find the corresponding position on the whole DNA (which would be 109 in this example).
The function should do the following:

```
function(gene, 9) 
> 109
function(gene, 10)
> 130
```

My approach is to explicitly generate the two sequences, concatenate them and take the n-th element of this list. However, for large lists (as they happen to occur), this is very inefficient.

Can anyone think of a simple way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so do you start your position counting from `1` instead of `0`? Otherwise I don't understand how `function(gene,10)` could be `109`.

Comment: You're right, my example was wrong. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution, should work for as many gaps in the gene as you want:

```
gene = [[100,110], [130,140]]

def function(gene, n):
    for span in gene:
        span_len = span[1] - span[0] 
        if n <= span_len:
            return n + span[0] - 1
        else:
            n -= span_len

print(function(gene,10))
print(function(gene,11))
```

Answer (score 0):

your `function` can be provided both lists and you can find which list you should be indexing and where using the size of the lists

so if you do `function(gene, 10)` and `function(gene, 11)`

`10 <= len(List1)` but `11 > len(list1)` so you know you need to access the second list in the case of `11`, and the right element is `11 - len(list1) -1` which is index 0 but for the second list.